# What does it mean: to roll into the wild

Tags: meaning, translation

Context: [Android 4.2.2: A better Jelly Bean **rolls into the wild**](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-57568901-1/android-4.2.2-a-better-jelly-bean-rolls-into-the-wild/). Does it mean that  Android 4.2.2 becomes something like an animal, something crazy?

Comment: "The wild" probably means that 4.2.2 isn't used exclusively for one kind of tablet or smart phone. It definitely doesn't mean that it "becomes something like an animal, something crazy".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that it is rolling out (made available to or push-updated) to the public - e.g. no longer in private beta

> The upgrade is being released to Nexus device owners first

Normally used about virusses - and then the expression is often *seen in the wild*

http://www.pctools.com/security-news/virus-in-the-wild/

> A virus is said to be “in the wild” if it is spreading uncontained among infected computers in the general public. It must be spreading on and between the computers of unsuspecting users as a result of normal day-to-day operations. A virus being studied in a controlled environment for research purposes would not be considered “in the wild.” Also, a virus (or Trojan) that exists but is not actively spreading is also not considered to be “in the wild.”